# Thrift sasl with username/password authentication for C++

Tags: authentication, visual-c++, thrift, sasl, cyrus

I've been trying to add security to my project which uses Apache Thrift. In C#, there is a class **TSASLClientTransport** which accepts the parameters TSocket, username and password. Similarly I need a cpp class so that I can implement the same in C++.

I came across this task https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1667, which is still in Open state. There's a patch available in this task though. Using this patch I imported the TsaslTransport class, but I don't find a way to provide username/password here. If possible can anyone share any examples on this.

Or is there a way to provide simple username/password authentication in thrift using C++?

Can [Cyrus-SASL](https://github.com/dinhviethoa/cyrus-sasl) be used here?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I found out a working solution. I’ve used [cyrus-sasl](https://github.com/dinhviethoa/cyrus-sasl) project along with the patch from [Apache THRIFT](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1667).

First create a TTransport with a hive service running in a secure cluster.

```
boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> socket(new TSocket("hive_host", hive_port));
boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> transport(new TBufferedTransport(socket));
```

Create array of Callbacks to get the username from &**simple** and password from &**getsecret** in client.

```
  static sasl_callback_t callbacks[] ={
           {
            SASL_CB_USER, (sasl_callback_ft)&simple, NULL 
           }, {
            SASL_CB_AUTHNAME, (sasl_callback_ft)&simple, NULL 
           }, {
            SASL_CB_PASS, (sasl_callback_ft)&getsecret, NULL
           }, {
            SASL_CB_LIST_END, NULL, NULL
           }
};
```

Use libSaslClient from saslimpl.cpp to choose the mechanism and service. This initializes the client. And use this client in TSaslTransport to open a connection and communicate with the server.

```
map<string, string> props; 
sasl::libSaslClient libSaslClient("PLAIN", "", "ldap", "host", props, callbacks);
boost::shared_ptr<TSaslTransport> tsaslTransport(new TSaslTransport(&libSaslClient, transport));
tsaslTransport->open();
tsaslTransport->close();
```

On successful open you will be able to communicate with a secure cluster given the right username and password.